# How to read/scan a .txt file in GO

Tags: go

The .txt file has many lines which each contain a single word. So I open the file and pass it to the reader:

```
file, err := os.Open("file.txt")
check(err)
reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
```

Now I want to store each line in a slice of strings. I believe I need to use ReadBytes, ReadString, ReadLine, or on of the Scan functions. Any advice on how to implement this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `r` as an instance of `*bufio.Reader`, and `myList` as a slice of strings, than one could just loop and read lines till EOL.

```
   for {
        line, err := r.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        myList = append(myList, string(line))
   }
```

Comment: Would the code you posted not just continue to read the 1st line of the file and append it to the list in an infinite loop?

Comment: No, thats not how reader works. What it will do is during each `for` iteration, read a line and append it to `myList` array. When there are no more lines to read, Reader will return an error, which will break the loop.

Comment: is myList a slice of Strings? When I tried your code with myList being a slice of strings I got an error: cannot convert myList (type []string) to type string

Comment: Yes. What is the line, the error is raised on? If you want to convert `[]string` to `string`, maybe you want to perform a join? http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join

Comment: `myList = append(myList, string(line)` my line that declares `myList` looks like `myList := make([]string, 0)`

Comment: My mistake, the error was from another line. Your solution worked!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ioutil.ReadFile()` to read all lines into a byte slice and then call `split` on the result:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/etc/passwd")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    lines := strings.Split(string(data), "\n")

    for _, line := range lines {
        fmt.Println("line:", string(line))
    }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I asked for, but I can't figure out how to access a particular line. Is there a way to index each line as a single integer? `len()` returns the size in bytes, so I don't see how I can find where each line starts.

Comment: @user2802602 you can access a specific line by indexing the `lines` slice: `lines[21]` gives you the 20th line.